# CRM 2011 - Supported version of javascript function to change currency symbol

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have this nice little javascript snippet for CRM 4.0 to update a form's Money fields to use the currency symbol I pass in as a string. ([source](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/crmdevelopment/thread/1a3be674-1173-478f-a5cd-864c73a21a24))

```
UpdateCurrencySymbolInUI: function (_curr) {
    // BTP: fail to update currency symbol if using browser other than IE (crmForm will not be defined)
    // (set currency not supported via Xrm.Page CRM 2011)
    if (!IsNull(crmForm)) {
        var iLen = crmForm.all.length;
        var oCtrl, i;

        for (i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
            oCtrl = crmForm.all[i];
            if (!IsNull(oCtrl.IsMoney) && !oCtrl.IsBaseCurrency) {
                oCtrl.CurrencySymbol = _curr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but for the coming change to multi-browser support (scheduled for 2012Q4 now, right?) [Microsoft's custom code validaiton tool suggests this code will not function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/06/21/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-custom-code-validation-tool-released.aspx) on any browser other than IE because the crmForm is no longer supported.

After some googling I don't see a supported alternative to setting the currency sybmol. Am I missing something in the API or did they just flat out remove this functionality to assign the currency symbol (through the API)? [This post suggests](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/crmdevelopment/thread/7c7e88bb-b49f-4d88-8fa5-a2608f9a406d) I use document.getElementById and add "_sym" to the fieldname, but I assume this is unsupported. I'd prefer a supported solution.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware, but your old code was also unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: not immediately obvious from the OP's question, but this behaviour (currency code not changed) is only exhibited if the `transactioncurrencyid` attribute is changed via JScript.

So this is what MS is still doing under the hood in CRM Online and On Premise UR5 (`img.lu.transcur.htc`). Looks pretty similar to me. Can't see anything here browser specific though... :

```
function updateCurrencySymbolInUI(){
    if(!IsNull(_oForm))
        for(var iLen=_oForm.all.length,oCtrl,i=0;i<iLen;i++){
            oCtrl=_oForm.all[i];
            if(!IsNull(oCtrl.IsMoney)&&!oCtrl.IsBaseCurrency){
                oCtrl.CurrencySymbol=_sCurSym;
               oCtrl.CurrencyPrecision=_iCurPre
            }        
        }
}
```

I think the issue with the code validation tool is because as you say `crmForm` is deprecated. Pass it a reference to the page's FORM object (`document.all['crmForm']`) in place of `crmForm`. I reckon that'll work nicely.

<s>Why do you need this code at all? If you change the transaction currency on a form that contains `Money` fields, the currency symbol in the control automatically changes to the symbol defined in Business Management > Currencies.</s>

If the symbol isn't the one you want to display, change it there :)

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned that the transactioncurrencyid changes via javascript. I like your answer, but I've realized working on this it really needs to be delayed until we have the rollup in our hands because we simply cannot test until then. Also can I ask why you suggest document.all['crmForm']? I am not familiar with that and just interested why it will be different. (EDIT: since I am deferring this I'll go ahead and pre-emptively mark yours as the answer and if/when this code gets revised after the rollup I'll update this thread with my results)